# TypeError when Dynamically Changing CSS in ReactJs Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to change the background color of my ReactJs web app dynamically when pressing the up arrow on a keyboard. However, when running this code, I am receiving the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

The component that this piece of code is placed in has one parent which renders the entire app.

```
handleKeyDownEvent(event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        event.preventDefault();

        /*if up key or swipe up*/
        if (this.state.isInverted == false) {
            document.getElementById("body").setAttribute("background-color", "#000000");
            this.setState({ isInverted: true });
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("body").setAttribute("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
            this.setState({ isInverted: false });
        }
    }
}
```

How would I fix this? Any suggestions on better methods to change the background color dynamically in React?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your markup? Doesn't seem like an element with id `body` exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to change the background color of the body element you can just do `document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'`

Answer (score 1):

**background-color** is not a html attribute, is a **css property**, you can change style attribute and then set background-color as a value for style attribute, for example:

```
document.getElementById("body").setAttribute("style", "background-color:#000000");
```

This line will be add a style attribute to the body tag:

```
<body style="background-color: #00000">
```